# pygame.time.get_ticks() can be Float and take numbers like 0.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

this is my first time here and i need help, actually i want to know how can i change the pygame.time.get_ticks() to be float and take numbers or a list of numbers like 0.1, 0.2 and more. I tried this in all the posible ways but i couldn't afford the solution. And the reason why i want to make it a Float number, because i want the image to change faster (o.1 seconds and not 1 second).

I'll pass all my code if you can see something that is wrong. Thanks

```
import sys
import pygame
import pygameMenu
from random import randint
from random import randrange
from pygame.locals import *
from pygameMenu.locals import*

# TEXTO PARA LOS MENUS

SOBRE_NOSOTROS = ['- Alvaro  Alejandro  Nuñez  Mendoza',
                  '- Claudio  Lisandro  Mori  Rivas',
                  '- Alejandro  Javier  Ortiz  Balazar',
                  '- Julio  Cesar  Huaman  Mendoza',
                  '- Rodrigo Rene  Ramos  Vargas',
                  '- Percy  Javier  Moreno  Vasquez']

COMO_JUGAR = ['- Presiona  Izquierda / Derecha  para   moverte',
              '- Presiona  Arriba  para  saltar',
              '- Presiona  "ESC"  para  salir  del  juego']

# Variables globales
ancho = 640
alto = 800

# Tamaño del menu del juego y colores
color_fondo = (128, 0, 128)
color_negro = (0,0,0)
color_blanco = (255,255,255)
color_fondo_menu = (228, 55, 36)
tamaño_del_menu = (640, 480)

# Funciones del menú
def cambiar_dificultad():
    pass

def background():
    fondoMenu = pygame.image.load("menuPantalla.png")
    ventana.blit(fondoMenu,(0,0))

def color_random():
    return randrange(0, 255), randrange(0, 255), randrange(0, 255)

class CRunner():
    def ChasquiRunner(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ancho, alto))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Chasqui Runner")
        self.imagenFondo = pygame.image.load("Carretera_Ver1.png")

        self.jugador = Chasqui(alto-200,(ancho/2)-70)

        self.reloj = pygame.time.Clock()

        while True:
            # Una vez subida la lista de imagenes se pone el tiempo para determinar el cambio
            self.segundos = int(pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000.0)
            # Definir los FPS del videojuego
            self.reloj.tick(60)
            self.eventos = pygame.event.get()

            for self.evento in self.eventos:
                if self.evento.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

                elif self.evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if self.evento.key == K_LEFT:
                        self.jugador.rect.left -= self.jugador.velocidad
                    if self.evento.key == K_RIGHT:
                        self.jugador.rect.right += self.jugador.velocidad
                    if self.evento.key == K_UP:
                        self.jugador.rect.top -= self.jugador.velocidad
                    if self.evento.key == K_DOWN:
                        self.jugador.rect.bottom += self.jugador.velocidad

            self.ventana.blit(self.imagenFondo, (0,0))
            self.jugador.comportamiento(self.segundos)
            self.jugador.dibujar(self.ventana)

            pygame.display.update()

# Programación del Chusqui Runner
class Chasqui(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, posx, posy):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Se va a hacer un cambio de todas las imagenes debido a que el chasqui va a tener que correr de forma dinámica, no estática
        self.imagen1 = pygame.image.load(r"model-chasqui\sprite_Chasqui00.png")
        self.imagen2 = pygame.image.load(r"model-chasqui\sprite_Chasqui01.png")
        self.imagen3 = pygame.image.load(r"model-chasqui\sprite_Chasqui02.png")
        self.imagen4 = pygame.image.load(r"model-chasqui\sprite_Chasqui03.png")
        self.imagen5 = pygame.image.load(r"model-chasqui\sprite_Chasqui04.png")
        self.imagen6 = pygame.image.load(r"model-chasqui\sprite_Chasqui05.png")
        self.imagen7 = pygame.image.load(r"model-chasqui\sprite_Chasqui06.png")
        self.imagen8 = pygame.image.load(r"model-chasqui\sprite_Chasqui07.png")
        self.imagen9 = pygame.image.load(r"model-chasqui\sprite_Chasqui08.png")
        self.imagen10 = pygame.image.load(r"model-chasqui\sprite_Chasqui09.png")
        self.imagen11 = pygame.image.load(r"model-chasqui\sprite_Chasqui10.png")

        # Luego esto se va a agregar a una lista para asi poder recorrerla y generar el movimiento del personaje
        self.listaImagenes = [self.imagen1, self.imagen2, self.imagen3, self.imagen4,
                              self.imagen5, self.imagen6, self.imagen7, self.imagen8,
                              self.imagen9, self.imagen10, self.imagen11]
        self.posImagen = 0

        # Se pone la imagen encime del fondo
        self.imagenesPosicion = self.listaImagenes[self.posImagen]
        self.rect = self.imagenesPosicion.get_rect()

        # Sirve para recorrer la imagen de acuerdo al tiempo que se le otorque
        self.tiempoCambio = 1  

        # La velocidad en la cual ira el chasqui
        self.velocidad = 20
        self.rect.top = posx
        self.rect.left = posy

    def dibujar(self, superficie):
        self.imagenesPosicion = self.listaImagenes[self.posImagen]
        superficie.blit(self.imagenesPosicion, self.rect)

    def comportamiento(self, tiempo):
        # En esta funcion se recorre la lista para hacer el cambio de imágenes y asi generar el movimiento
        if self.tiempoCambio == tiempo:
            self.posImagen += 1
            self.tiempoCambio += 1

            if self.posImagen > len(self.listaImagenes)-1:
                self.posImagen = 0

class Obstaculos(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Estas con los distintos objetos o obstaculos que iran apareciendo en el juego y en posiciones random
        self.imagen = pygame.image.load("Obstaculo1.jpg")
        self.imagen1 = pygame.image.load("Obstaculo2.jpg")
        self.imagen2 = pygame.image.load("Obstaculo3.jpg")

        # Se usa un listado de imágenes para poder usar las distintas imagenes de una forma mas sencilla
        self.listaObstaculos = [self.imagen, self.imagen1, self.imagen2]
        self.posImagen = 0

        self.imagenesObstaculos = self.listaObstaculos[self.posImagen]
        self.rect = self.imagenesObstaculos.get_rect()

        self.velocidad = 10
        self.rect.top = posx
        self.rect.left = posy

    def dibujar(self, superficie):
        self.imagenesObstaculos = self.listaObstaculos[posImagen]
        superficie.blit (self.imagenesObstaculos, self.rect)

#    -----   MENU   -----
# MENU DEL JUEGO
class GameMenu():
    def menu_del_juego(self):
        self.menu_jugar = pygameMenu.Menu(ventana,
                                        bgfun=background,
                                        color_selected=color_blanco,
                                        font=pygameMenu.fonts.FONT_BEBAS,
                                        font_color=color_negro,
                                        font_size=30,
                                        menu_alpha=0,
                                        menu_height=int(tamaño_del_menu[1]),
                                        menu_width=int(tamaño_del_menu[0]),
                                        onclose=PYGAME_MENU_DISABLE_CLOSE,
                                        option_shadow=False,
                                        title='Menu Principal',
                                        window_height=tamaño_del_menu[1],
                                        window_width=tamaño_del_menu[0]
                                        )

        self.menu_jugar.add_option('Empezar!', game.ChasquiRunner)
        self.menu_jugar.add_selector('Poner dificultad', [('Facil', 'FACIL'),
                                                     ('Medio', 'MEDIO'),
                                                     ('Dificil', 'DIFICIL')],
                                onreturn = False,
                                onchange = cambiar_dificultad)
        self.menu_jugar.add_option('Salir', PYGAME_MENU_BACK)

    # MENU SOBRE NOSOTROS
        self.menu_sobre_nosotros = pygameMenu.TextMenu(ventana,
                                                bgfun=background,
                                                color_selected=color_blanco,
                                                font=pygameMenu.fonts.FONT_BEBAS,
                                                font_color=color_negro,
                                                font_size=30,
                                                menu_alpha=0,
                                                menu_height=int(tamaño_del_menu[1]),
                                                menu_width=int(tamaño_del_menu[0]),
                                                onclose=PYGAME_MENU_DISABLE_CLOSE,
                                                option_shadow=False,
                                                title='SOBRE NOSOTROS',
                                                window_height=tamaño_del_menu[1],
                                                window_width=tamaño_del_menu[0]
                                                )
        self.menu_sobre_nosotros.add_option("REGRESAR AL MENU PRINCIPAL", PYGAME_MENU_BACK)
        for self.m in SOBRE_NOSOTROS:
            self.menu_sobre_nosotros.add_line(self.m)
        self.menu_sobre_nosotros.add_line(PYGAMEMENU_TEXT_NEWLINE)

    # MENU COMO JUGAR
        self.menu_como_jugar = pygameMenu.TextMenu(ventana,
                                            bgfun=background,
                                            color_selected=color_blanco,
                                            font=pygameMenu.fonts.FONT_BEBAS,
                                            font_color=color_negro,
                                            font_size=30,
                                            menu_alpha=0,
                                            menu_height=int(tamaño_del_menu[1] ),
                                            menu_width=int(tamaño_del_menu[0]),
                                            onclose=PYGAME_MENU_DISABLE_CLOSE,
                                            option_shadow=False,
                                            title='COMO JUGAR',
                                            window_height=tamaño_del_menu[1],
                                            window_width=tamaño_del_menu[0]
                                            )
        self.menu_como_jugar.add_option("REGRESAR AL MENU PRINCIPAL", PYGAME_MENU_BACK)
        for self.m in COMO_JUGAR:
            self.menu_como_jugar.add_line(self.m)
        self.menu_como_jugar.add_line(PYGAMEMENU_TEXT_NEWLINE)

    # MENU PRINCIPAL
        self.menu_principal = pygameMenu.Menu(ventana,
                                        bgfun=background,
                                        color_selected=color_blanco,
                                        font=pygameMenu.fonts.FONT_BEBAS,
                                        font_color=color_negro,
                                        font_size=30,
                                        menu_alpha=0,
                                        menu_height=int(tamaño_del_menu[1]),
                                        menu_width=int(tamaño_del_menu[0]),
                                        onclose=PYGAME_MENU_DISABLE_CLOSE,
                                        option_shadow=False,
                                        title='Menu Principal',
                                        window_height=tamaño_del_menu[1],
                                        window_width=tamaño_del_menu[0]
                                        )

        self.menu_principal.add_option('Empezar Juego', self.menu_jugar)
        self.menu_principal.add_option('Sobre Nosotros', self.menu_sobre_nosotros)
        self.menu_principal.add_option('Como jugar', self.menu_como_jugar)
        self.menu_principal.add_option('Salir', PYGAME_MENU_EXIT)

        # Loop del menu
        while True:
            # FPS DEL JUEGO
            clock.tick(60)
            # Eventos del menu
            eventos = pygame.event.get()
            for evento in eventos:
                if evento.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            # MENU PRINCIPAL
            self.menu_principal.mainloop(eventos)

            # Flip
            pygame.display.flip()


# INICIALIZACIÓN DEL JUEGO
pygame.init()

game = CRunner()

ventana = pygame.display.set_mode(tamaño_del_menu)
pygame.display.set_caption("CHASQUI RUNNER MENU")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Comenzamos a llamar a la clase GameMenu para inicializar el Menú del juego
game_menu = GameMenu()
game_menu.menu_del_juego()
```

Comment: I don't use pygame often, but ticks refers to the internal game engine, you can't directly modify this value as it's dictated by pygame's event loop. I doubt they'd use anything but an int, if you want to slow it down, you need to look at the pygame docs for changing tick speed via the engine. Otherwise you'd have to hack your own slow motion framework on top of it by duplicating input and frames over a period of frameticks.

Comment: `get_ticks()` does not take in any arguments. I think you want to use `Clock.tick()`, and at that point the larger the number the faster your screen will update.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

pygame ticks are in milliseconds. An interval of 0.1 seconds lasts for 100 ticks; you do not need floats for that. If your game appears to be running at one frame per second, you have some other problem, perhaps the part where you *explicitly convert ticks to an integer number of seconds*:

```
self.segundos = int(pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000.0)
```

Stop doing that. Work with ticks, or at least remove the `int` call.

Comment: That's another problem and i dont know why, if i don use the `int` call, the image doens't move.